# Protobuf-net - How to add same field in inherited class with backward version compatibility

Tags: .net, protobuf-net

Let's say I have below classes structure:

Base class:

```
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(10, typeof(Store))]
[ProtoInclude(11, typeof(House))]
public abstract class Address
{
   [ProtoMember(1)] Id ;
   [ProtoMember(2)] string Country;
}
```

Child Class 1:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class Store: Address
{
   [ProtoMember(1)] int StoreUniqueid;
   [ProtoMember(2)] string StoreUniqueValue;
   [ProtoMember(3)] string Pincode;
}
```

Child Class 2:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class House : Address
{
   [ProtoMember(1)] int HouseArea;
}
```

Now, I have a situation where I need to introduce the "Pincode" property of Store class to the House Class.

What should be the ideal way to address this issue to maintain the backward compatibility?

Option 1: Move the Pincode property of the Store class to the Address (base) class. However, this may create a backward compatibility issue since we have to remove the Pincode property from the Store class.

Option 2: Add another same property(Pincode) inside the House class as below (Not sure whether this would be a right approach.)

```
[ProtoContract]
public class House: Address
{
   [ProtoMember(1)] int HouseArea;
   [ProtoMember(2)] string Pincode;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fields are scoped by the inheritance level; adding an additional field at the base level will not cause any conflicts at the derived level. If your intent is to still be able to *deserialize* the old format, then you can replace the derived `Pincode` with:

```cs
    [ProtoMember(3)]
    private string PincodeDeserializeCompat // only for deserialization
    {
        get => Pincode;
        set => Pincode = value;
    }
    private bool ShouldSerializePincodeDeserializeCompat() => false;
```

The `ShouldSerialize*` method disables serialization of this member going forwards; you could *also* try using:

```
    [ProtoMember(3)]
    private string PincodeDeserializeCompat // only for deserialization
    {
        get => null; // disable serialize
        set => Pincode = value;
    }
```